# Simple switch causes stack overflow

Tags: c#, stack-overflow

Why this simple code causes fallowing error :

Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state.

```
private void barButtonPanelVisibleCheck_CheckedChanged(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    switch (barButtonPanelVisibleCheck.Checked)
    {
        case true:
            this.navBarControl.Visible = false;
            this.barButtonPanelVisibleCheck.Checked = false;
            break;
        case false:
            this.navBarControl.Visible = true;
            this.barButtonPanelVisibleCheck.Checked = true;
            break;
    }

    //or

    if (barButtonPanelVisibleCheck.Checked == true)
    {
        this.navBarControl.Visible = false;
        this.barButtonPanelVisibleCheck.Checked = false;
    }
    else
    {
        this.navBarControl.Visible = true;
        this.barButtonPanelVisibleCheck.Checked = true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you changing the state of the checkbox in the event anyway? By virtue of the user clicking the checkbox its state has already been modified. Just remove those lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are trying to change the checked state of your checkbox while you are inside the `CheckedChanged` event, you raise another CheckedChanged event, and this starts an infinite loop that consume the stack memory until you reach the StackOverflow exception.

Try to stop the recursion on your CheckedChanged event with

```
 private void barButtonPanelVisibleCheck_CheckedChanged(object sender, 
                             DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
 {
       try
       {

           this.barButtonPanelVisibleCheck.CheckedChanged -=  
                barButtonPanelVisibleCheck_CheckedChanged;

           ... do your checked changed here

       }
       finally
       {
            this.barButtonPanelVisibleCheck.CheckedChanged +=  
                barButtonPanelVisibleCheck_CheckedChanged;
       }
 }
```

Disconnecting the Event handler allows to change the checked state without reentry the event handler, after that, reconnect the event. Probably for this scenarion there is no need to use a try/finally but using `finally` will ensure that the event is always reconnected in case your code fails with an exception.

Answer (score 3):

You are changing Checked from within the Checked handler: Checked value is set, so the handler is called, which sets Checked value etc. and you have an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

When checked state of the control is changed, method `barButtonPanelVisibleCheck_CheckedChanged` is called. In that method you change the `Checked` property of that control, which causes call to method barButtonPanelVisibleCheck_CheckedChanged. In that method you change the Checked property of that control.